# Zend Framework document root setup

Tags: zend-framework

My problem maybe easy to solve, but I really can't figure it out.

I followed the instructions in the book "Beginning Zend framework" creating a new project. 
The project has 2 controllers 'account' and 'artist'. Here is the tree view of /application:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── Bootstrap.php
│   ├── configs
│   │   └── application.ini
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── AccountController.php
│   │   ├── ArtistController.php
│   │   ├── ErrorController.php
│   │   └── IndexController.php
│   ├── models
│   └── views
│       ├── helpers
│       └── scripts
│           ├── account
│           │   ├── activate.phtml
│           │   ├── index.phtml
│           │   ├── new.phtml
│           │   └── success.phtml
│           ├── artist
│           │   ├── index.phtml
│           │   └── list-all-artists.phtml
│           ├── error
│           │   └── error.phtml
│           └── index
│               └── index.phtml
```

How can I setup document root to access /account/new.phtml, for example? (When typing 127.0.0.1, I can see the default index page "Welcome to the Zend Framework!", but I don't know how to access other pages).

More information:
+) The document root is /.../public/ (which contains .htacess and index.php)
+) 127.0.0.1/index also returns that page, but 127.0.0.1/index/index.phtml does not work.
http://127.0.0.1/account, http://127.0.0.1/artist return 404 error.

Comment: First thing to do, before reading any tutorial or any book: [read the Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html#learning.quickstart.intro.zf). This will help you to understand basically how Zend Framework works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to ZF! A personal thing I do is always setup a Vhost, rather than just use the standard "`localhost`". This really helps with the management of separate projects, and allows you to store it in an easier location.

If you try to do localhost/account, what happens? If you get any type of errors, then you haven't setup Apache properly. Here's a sample `Vhost` that I use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project.local
   DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public"


   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Go ahead and try to do something similar, and create the respective line in your `HOSTS` file, clear your cache, and you should be set!

Also, in your structure, I noticed you're missing a `public` folder. Be sure you have one, along with a `.htaccess` to rewrite to `index.php`. Edit: just saw your edit, you should already have this taken care of.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the problem seems not to be solved. Please see if this configuration is correct: (thanks!)`code`NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName hello.local
        DocumentRoot "C:\Apache\htdocs\helloworld\public"
     
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     
        <Directory "C:\Apache\htdocs\helloworld\public">
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost> `code`

Comment: Same as before, http://127.0.0.1/ gives contents of the file 'C:\Apache\htdocs\helloworld\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml', but http://127.0.0.1/account gives 'Not Found'

Comment: @user1046862 you forgot the `FollowSymlinks` in your directory declaration. This is kind of important when using ZF, because all requests route through `index.php`

Comment: I see you're using windows, don't forget to update your `Hosts` file when using vhosts. This [link](http://blog.srmklive.com/2010/12/27/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-using-zend-server-ce/) will provide good advice on how to build a vhost for ZF, it is aimed at Zend Server but should easily adapt to any server using apache.

Comment: I got the problem solved under Ubuntu, but not Windows. Please see what's wrong with the configuration: `code` 
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache\htdocs\loudbite\public"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName helloworld.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache\htdocs\loudbite\public"
 
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
 
    <Directory "C:\Apache\htdocs\loudbite\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`code`

Comment: And if I use @tcole's suggestion, it will raise an 'Internal Server Error' ? The code I posted above is from [link](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts#zfbook.creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts.configuring.apache.with.virtual.hosts)

Comment: @user1046862 What's the error in your error log? That came straight from my Windows Apache vhosts conf file.

Comment: In the end, I tried Zend Server CE and it worked! Thank you you all for your answers and comments.

Comment: Glad you got it working :-) Feel free to mark the answer as solved.